# re-sorting a stream of data using python

Tags: python, sorting, hex

Currently I am  working on a stream of hex data like this:

```
FIX230000010056A898
FIX230000020067A898
FIX230000030067A898
...
```

and so on, I got it from the microcontroller output. But somehow, if there is error, the data is shifted, so the data stream become like:

```
00010067A898FIX2300
00020067A898FIX2300
00030067A898FIX2300
```

which trouble me when i try to decode the data. I have to arrange manually so that the `FIX2300` characters will be in the beginning of data again, but it's just too troublesome. So, i wanted to write the program in python... but unfortunately have no idea. Is there anyone, who knows about this? very much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import binascii

myStr = "00010067A898FIX2300"

#or
myHex = b'30303031303036374138393846495832333030'
myStr2 = binascii.unhexlify(myHex).decode('utf8')
# NOTE: myStr2 = myStr

# convert stream data to string
myStr3 = myStr[-7:]+myStr[:-7] # or myStr2[-7:]+myStr2[:-7]

#convert stream data back to hex, if needed
myHex2 = binascii.hexlify(myStr.encode('utf8'))
```

You can use 'ascii' codec instead of 'utf8', too.

Comment: Yes! that was what i was looking for. And I think to sort all lines, i can use repeat using 'for' command. Thanks a lot!